# Install ubuntu in a endless so installed pc

Tags: system-installation

I bought a laptop with endless O.S. and I'm trying to install ubuntu on it, however, ubuntu installer doesn't run (it keeps in loading menu for a long time and doesn't start ubuntu's installation).
Can someone help me?

Comment: Perhaps you will get a better response if you explain the steps you made trying to start the Ubuntu installer; i.e. what install medium you created, showing screenshots, etc.

Comment: Do you mean [Endless OS?](https://www.distrowatch.com/?newsid=10114) Sorry, but I have no idea what "endless so" means. Please review https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask voting unclear.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it. The error wasn't the old O.S. , but the graphic card, it was a Nvidia and I couldn't install because of the errors of Ubuntu 15 and superiors with Nvidia cards.
I solved it installing Ubuntu 14.04